# document.readyState not working in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, dom-events, document, document-ready

In my application, I am calling a method for every **1000ms** to check the document `readyState`. Following is the code which I am using:

```
var success=setInterval(""CheckState()"",1000);

function CheckState(){

if($get('businessDownl').document.readyState=="interactive" || 
      $get('businessDownl').document.readyState=="complete"){
           alert("Great");
           clearInterval(success);
  } 
}
```

This code works fine in IE browser, but fails in Firefox and Chrome browsers. I tried using
`$get('businessDownl').readyState` also, it is printing as undefined. Can anybody tell me how to use the `readyState` for Firefox and Chrome in the above scenario?

Comment: What is `$get('businessDownl')` supposed to return ?

Comment: Am creating an ifram. var businessDownl= document.createElement(""iframe"");

Comment: why do you need `""CheckState()""` ? two sets of opening and closing quotes ?

Comment: is the source of the this iFrame on the same domain as your webpage ?

Comment: @harsha. Actually I Copied the Javascript from vb. So pls Ignore that. The code works fine in IE. It strucks only when it is checking the document.readyState

Comment: @Cyril : Did you check the chrome debugger or the firebug console ?

Comment: Yes. I am using console.log for printing the $get('businessDownl').document.readyState. It is throwing an exception. When I googled , they are saying document.readyState is not supported

Comment: What is `$get` anyway ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NOTE:** In order to be able to access the document of an iframe and thus it's `readyState`, you need to have access to the domain in the iframe (regadless of the use of jQuery).
For more info, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

---

You could do it using the iframe's `contentWindow` property (no jQuery required).
Note that, in order to access the iframe's `document`, you have to add the element to the DOM first (e.g. using `window.document.appendChild()`).

Sample code:

```
var businessDownl = document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(businessDownl);
...
var state = businessDownl.contentWindow.document.readyState;
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/wD49T/)**.
[Tested on latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.]

(Notice that, because the iframe loads quickly, sometimes you see only "completed", sometimes "loading" and "completed" - once I was even lucky enough to see "uninitialized" too :D).

Comment: In order for this to work you have to have access to the domain in the iframe

Comment: @Krets: True, but this was not an issue for the OP. (The question was pretty specific, so the answer is not likely to apply to a broad set of cases.) Adding a little "heads-up", though, won't hurt, so _good point_. Thx !

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It takes about 10 seconds before the browser prompts me to download the file the iframe downloading. But the `iframe.contentWindow.document.readyState` is `"complete"` immediately for IE, Chrome, or Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to wait until the document is ready there is no need to keep checking - you can listen for the event:

```
var whenReady = function(callback) {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') callback(); // check not already loaded prior to this function being called
  else if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback); // for standards compliant browsers (including IE 9+)
  else if (document.attachEvent) document.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', callback); // for IE 8
};

whenReady(alert('loaded'));
```

The only downside of this technique is that it only supports IE 8 and later. Libraries such as JQuery offer better legacy browser support and a cleaner syntax:

```
$(function() {
  // anything here will execute once the dom is ready
});
```