# Detecting an iframe's onload in Chrome when downloading files

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, onload

I'm using a hidden iframe in an HTML page for downloading purposes. And I would like to know when it's done. I've searched the Internet a lot and everyone says that I should use iframe's `onload` event handler but it's not working for me in Chrome!

I'm not sure where but I read somewhere that it's because I'm downloading files with my iframe instead of HTML documents. And I must admit that it's specific to Chrome and it works fine in FireFox.

I've also tested `readstate` and `onreadystatechange` without success.

I've created a fiddle to demonstrate the problem:

```js
function download(url)
{
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = url;
    iframe.onload = function () {
        console.log('Download completed.');
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="download('http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/peace.zip');">Download</button>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
function downloadURL(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader',
        iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.onload = function () {
            alert('Download completed.');
        };
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="downloadURL('http://www.colorado.edu/conflict/peace/download/peace.zip');">Download</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, it would nice to point out that the problem relies in the order of code and that `iframe.src = url;` should be done at the end.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, at least in Firefox. The event never fires.

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689273), [and here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548984), [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9249680)

Comment: This does not work, tested in latest Firefox and Chrome