# document.getElementById('myframe').readyState is "undefined" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I have a iframe in aspx page i have to check the readyState conditions as shown below, please let me know how to get the readystate of iframe control using javascript.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {      
            var iframe = document.getElementById('myframe').readyState;
            alert(iframe); // iframe is giving "undefined" here
        }
</script>


<div>
<iframe id="myframe" name="myframename" frameborder="1" src="about:blank"> </iframe>
</div>
```

thanks
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

That's because the iFrame itself does not have a readyState. You'll need to access the contentWindow (child of the iFrame) to get that result. See [document.readyState not working in Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689273/document-readystate-not-working-in-firefox-and-chrome)
(and some more here: [Iframe.readyState does not work in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952942/iframe-readystate-does-not-work-in-chrome) )